# Excel VBA - How do I clear the clipboard on another workbook in another application?

Tags: vba, excel

## Background:

I have a script that is formatting Raw Data and appending it to the end of an analysis workbook I have open. The script runs from the analysis workbook as the RAW Data is populated each time.

## Issue:

The script works fine with one exception, I am unable to clear the clipboard on the other workbook and I suspect that this is due to it being open in another instance(Application) of Excel.

## My Code So Far:

```
Sub Data_Ready_For_Transfer()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rnglog As Range
    Dim lastrow As Range
    Dim logrange As Range
    Dim vlastrow As Range
    Dim vlastcol As Range
    Dim copydata As Range
    Dim pastecell As Range
    Dim callno As Range

    Set wb = GetObject("Book1")
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'if we get workbook instance then
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        With wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            DisplayAlerts = False
            ScreenUpdating = False
            .Cells.RowHeight = 15
            Set rnglog = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("1:1").Find(What:="Log Date", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            Set lastrow = rnglog.EntireColumn.Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            Set logrange = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(rnglog, lastrow)
            rnglog.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
            rnglog.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
            rnglog.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
            rnglog.EntireColumn.TextToColumns Destination:=rnglog, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
                Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
                :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 9)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            rnglog.Value = "Log Date"
            rnglog.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Time"
            logrange.Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=WEEKNUM(RC[-2])"
            logrange.Offset(0, 2).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "General"
            rnglog.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Week Number"
            logrange.Offset(0, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-3],""mmmm"")"
            logrange.Offset(0, 3).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "General"
            rnglog.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Month"
            Set vlastrow = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            Set vlastcol = vlastrow.EntireRow.Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            Set copydata = .Range("A2", vlastcol)
            copydata.Copy
        End With
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RAW Data")
            Set pastecell = .Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            Set callno = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="Call No", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
            pastecell.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=5, Header:=xlYes
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
        wb.Close False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "Done"
    End If
End Sub
```

I thought I would get round the issue by closing the RAW Data workbook (I want to do this anyway) but I get a prompt as the clipboard data is rather large so this also doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` to block the prompt? I can see you set DisplayAlerts on the Sheet, but this might not extend to the Application as a whole.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but with no success. I assume that is because it is applying the `DisplayAlerts = False` to the current application and not the other one.

Comment: @Petay87, maybe something like this: `wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False`?

Comment: @simoco I could have sworn I tried that but yet again you have come to the rescue! That worked!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since workbook `wb` belongs to *another* application instance, you should use

```
wb.Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

instead

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

where `wb.Application` returns applications instance which workbook `wb` belongs to.

Comment: Interesting to note that in Excel 2010, both `True` and `False` are translated into `xlCopy`. The other option for `CutCopyMode` is `xlCut`. Setting it to `xlCopy` does seem to clear the clipboard and allow the file to close.

Answer (score 5):

What I do is just copy any blank cell in my ActiveWorkbook once I have pasted the values that I copied earlier and I don't need them any more - and this replaces the large data in the Clipboard with an empty string (comparatively nothing) and allows me to close the workbook when I need to.

I understand this is rather a workaround, but it works all the time.

**Another Solution**

What you should try is to get the `MSForms DataObject` and try to put it in clipboard

```
Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
```

and then clear it as following:

```
clipboard.Clear
```

And if this doesn't work, you can always set the clipboard text to empty

```
clipboard.SetText ""
clipboard.PutInClipboard
```

Comment: That does the trick but it would be really handy if I knew how to apply the clear clip board to the other application as I may not have wanted to close the application.

Comment: When I started looking for the solution, all I found was to use `Application.CutCopyMode = False`. And, I am not sure why this doesn't work for me and it seems it doesn't work for you either. Please look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `Application.CutCopyMode =  False` did not work for me to clear the buffer or stop getting an error when trying `ActiveSheet`. Paste `errorActiveSheet`. Paste error

To clear a large buffer, which is producing an `ActiveSheet`.Paste error for example is to simply copy an empty cell, for example `Range("A1").Copy`, where cell A1 would be empty or very small. This will then make the buffer really small! Easy fix! Maybe not precisely correct, but it is functionally correct.

Comment: IMHO, the best way is to combine these 2 methods. First, we copy single cell in Excel (and it takes the clipboard): `Range("A1").Copy`; and then set CutCopyMode to False: `Application.CutCopyMode =  False`.