# How can I clear the clipboard after taking a screenshot (Application.cutcopymode = False doesn't work)?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-word, copy-paste

I'm taking a screenshot using an API call.  The problem is, that screenshot will stay on the clipboard and `Application.CutCopyMode = False` only works if you've copied something straight from Excel.

One workaround is to just copy something in  Excel after taking the screenshot and then using `Application.CutCopyMode`, but if there is a more official way of doing this it would be helpful.  So far I have tried the following but it didn't work

```
Sub clear()
    Dim db As MSForms.DataObject
    db.clear
End Sub
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324699/excel-vba-how-do-i-clear-the-clipboard-on-another-workbook-in-another-applicat

Comment: This is where I got the code above that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Sorry, actually the 2nd half of that solution which use the SetText and PutInClipboard methods does work.  Thank you.  It is worth nothing though that for some reason the clear method doesn't work

Comment: Incidentally, you can take a screen shot without an API call using: `Application.SendKeys "(%{1068})" : DoEvents`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a module called globals and put these there.

```
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
```

Then use this code from wherever.

```
OpenClipboard (0&)
EmptyClipboard
CloseClipboard
```

Comment: this works great and is exactly what i was looking for, thanks.  What does the "0&" value mean?  I somewhat understand that the paramater is used as a handle for the clipboard but I'm not familiar with "0&"

Comment: A handle to the window to be associated with the open clipboard. If this parameter is NULL, the open clipboard is associated with the current task. See here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649048(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: HWND is a windows data type.  See here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I"m not sure I understand this part: "If this parameter is NULL, the open clipboard is associated with the current task."  Is there more than one possible clipboard?

Comment: Not sure on that one myself. Maybe the window that has focus.  That would be a good topic to open another question.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because `application.cutcopymode = false` stop the copy cut mode but doesn't clear the clipboard.

Maybe you can set the clipboard with an empty string like this :

```
Dim emptyDataString as DataObject
Set emptyDataString = new DataObject 
emptyDataString.SetText ""
emptyDataString.PutInClipboard
```