# how to clear clipboard content from word vba?

Tags: vba

I'm working with VBA on ms Word.It run the word document copy the content to paste other document then process.After the finished process when closing the document display "large amount of text" warning.How do i over come this help me
any one.

```
ActiveDocument.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveDocument.Close
Application.Quit
```

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22325055/1911064).

Comment: Thank's Axel. It's working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - How do I clear the clipboard on another workbook in another application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22324699/excel-vba-how-do-i-clear-the-clipboard-on-another-workbook-in-another-applicat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to clear the clipboard and stop the clipboard message.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```