# Unable to suppress clipboard warning message when closing a file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Macro that opens a workbook (wb1) and copies it into another workbook (wb2), then closes wb1. However I am always prompted the message below that there is a large amount of clipboard data which I don't want to be prompted. After doing some research I found putting the 'Application.CutCopyMode' set to false (which clears the clipboard) would resolve this issue but it hasn't.

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
...

'copy the range from source book
 wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:V2").Copy
 'paste the data on the target book
 wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:V2").PasteSpecial

wb.Close savechanges:=False
```

[image]

How can I close the file without this message?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22328170/1153513 Note, that you'll have to clear the clipboard for the originating workbook. So, it should be in your example `wb1.Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to suppress any messages, add the following before closing the file:

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

If you want to clear the clipboard content, you should add the `Application.CutCopyMode = False` after performing the Copy/Paste operations. Like this:

```
...

'copy the range from source book
wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:V2").Copy
'paste the data on the target book
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:V2").PasteSpecial

Application.CutCopyMode = False

wb.Close savechanges:=False
```

Comment: But what if other important alerts come up?

Comment: Ah, ok...you want to just suppress that warning. In that case you should the `Application.CutCopyMode = False` after you perform the Copy/Paste actions and you can drop the `Application.DisplayAlerts = FALSE` Statement. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is the special pasting you want to do? If you just want to copy the values across, then instead of copying & pasting, just assign the values directly:

```
wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:V2").value = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:V2").value
```